# Combine same data into one row

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZPB8.png)

I've searched a number of times but I cannot find the correct query to fit what I am trying to do. In the example image, I would like to have all matching data into one row and have the numbers under the Recommendation(s) column combined with commas using pl/sql in an Apex Interactive Report application.

To look like this:

0177||Martinez, Melchor||24-OCT-13||1||17||1,2,8||
0178||Saxon, Victoria  ||16-OCT-13||2||748||4,5||

Comment: Oracle or sql server?

Comment: Why using pl/sql? Or did you mean using Oracle SQL? There is no need for pl/sql here. Also, what is special about Apex Interactive Report? I assume "nothing", but please clarify.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the table data, with column names?  Do you want to combine the results of one column from several rows into one column in the Interactive Report?

Comment: This is part of my query: select
    c.CR_MDT_DT,
    c.CR_MDT_PRESENTED,
    c.CR_MDT_STAGE,
    c.CR_MDT_PHYS,
    c.CR_MDT_CT,
    c.CR_MDT_CN,
    c.CR_MDT_CM,
    c.CR_MDT_PT,
    c.CR_MDT_PN,
    c.CR_MDT_PM,
    a.SUBJECT_NUMBER,
    b.PTLASTNAME || ', ' || b.PTFIRSTNAME as "Patient name",
    d.VERIFICATION_TYPE,
e.CR_MDT_RECOM
from CR_MDT c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-MON-rr';   -- NOT PART OF THE QUERY

with test_data ( subject_number, patient, mdt_date, pres_phys, cr_mdt_phys, recomm ) as (
  select '0177', 'Martinez, Melchior', to_date ('24-OCT-13'), 1,  17, 1 from dual union all
  select '0177', 'Martinez, Melchior', to_date ('24-OCT-13'), 1,  17, 2 from dual union all
  select '0177', 'Martinez, Melchior', to_date ('24-OCT-13'), 1,  17, 8 from dual union all
  select '0178', 'Saxon, Victoria'   , to_date ('16-OCT-13'), 2, 748, 4 from dual union all
  select '0178', 'Saxon, Victoria'   , to_date ('16-OCT-13'), 2, 748, 5 from dual
)
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing purposes only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select subject_number patient, mdt_date, pres_phys, cr_mdt_phys,
       listagg(recomm, ',') within group (order by recomm) as recommendations
from   test_data
group by subject_number, patient, mdt_date, pres_phys, cr_mdt_phys
order by subject_number, patient, mdt_date, pres_phys, cr_mdt_phys  --  If needed
;

PATIENT  MDT_DATE   PRES_PHYS  CR_MDT_PHYS  RECOMMENDATIONS
-------  ---------  ---------  -----------  ---------------
0177     24-OCT-13          1           17  1,2,8
0178     16-OCT-13          2          748  4,5
```

Comment: Thanks that did it.

Comment: @idkfa.bfg2 - If this is the correct answer, you should mark it so.

Comment: Thanks Mathguy. New to this. Wanted to add, to use "Recommendations".